# How to show corresponding keypoints?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I would like to show in console corresponding size and angle of KeyPoints. I know how to detect it but I dont know what are properly index to show. I want to get result like keypoints1.size and keypoints1.angle is similar to keypoints2.size and keypoints2.angle. Below I got start of program:

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img1,keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2,keypoints2);

SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
extractor.compute(img1,keypoints1,descriptors1);
extractor.compute(img2,keypoints2,descriptors2);

BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

Comment: opencv3.0 has a 'drawMatches' method, that draws both of the images, with lines connecting the correspondences.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for(auto& m : matches) {
  cout << "Keypoints 1 angle: " << keypoints1[m.queryIdx].angle << endl;
  cout << "Keypoints 2 angle: " << keypoints2[m.trainIdx].angle << endl;
}
```

Change `.angle` property to show what you need

Comment: I thought like you but when I run my code I got results: 
Keypoints 1 angle: 221.835 
Keypoints 2 angle: 359.637 
Keypoints 1 angle: 4.20466 
Keypoints 2 angle: 185.558 Keypoints 1 angle: 358.279 Keypoints 2 angle: 271.689 Keypoints 1 angle: 3.03997 Keypoints 2 angle: 98.3456 and I think that I should receive very close to numbers?

Comment: no because you can have outliers and the object in the query image can rotate